# How to skip report file generation on Allure-Report jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, allure

i wanna know if there is a way to skip the report file generation on allure-report jenkins plugin on post-build action.

I want this because in my scenario i generate the files on build steps already `(i need to check this archives before the build ends)`.

But then i need to call the allure plugin on post-build actions `(to jenkins know that i'm using allure and show me the reports on build and build history)`.

But with this the plugin automatically generate the files again and i want use that ones that i've already created and cheked on build step.

Thanks

Comment: are you running a PIPELINE or regular job ?

Comment: i'm running a regular job.

Comment: Not sure you can in regular job , for sure in pipeline you can do it